# Shortcut to evaluate an expression on the REPL in Cursive Clojure?

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure, shortcut

I want to be able to send the current expression to the REPL for evaluation in Cursive Clojure. I can do this in emacs. Does anybody know what the keyboard shortcut for doing this in Cursive Clojure is?

I'm looking for the Cursive Clojure equivalent of `C-M-x`

Edit:
In [this Tim Baldridge video (at 2.47)](https://tbaldridge.pivotshare.com/media/function-of-the-day-juxt/11920/feature) you can see he has evaluates expressions in the repl using a keybinding.

[image: Evaluating expressions in Cursive Clojure using keybindings]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [official site](https://cursiveclojure.com/userguide/):

> **Key bindings**
>
> Currently Cursive is distributed without any shortcuts
>   assigned to its actions - it’s too difficult to avoid conflicts with
>   existing actions on all platforms. We’ll be suggesting some possible
>   keybindings for various features of Cursive as we discuss them. When
>   we talk about Mac keybindings we refer to the Mac OS X 10.5+ keymap,
>   which is what we use - not the old Mac OS X one.

Assign your shortcuts yourself, [here is how](https://cursiveclojure.com/userguide/paredit.html). See section **keymaps**.

Comment: Sure - but that link is shortcuts for editing and moving - not for evaluation.

Comment: The commands you're looking for are under the _Tools->REPL_ menu. Go to _Settings->Keymaps_, then collapse the whole action tree at the right. Then navigate to _Main Menu->Tools->REPL_, all the actions are there. You're probably looking for any or all of "Load file in REPL", "Run top form in REPL", or "Run form before cursor in REPL".

Comment: I can see 'Send' variants but no 'Run' variants. Presumably 'Run' means send it to the REPL then evaluate it there (equivalent of what I can do by wrapping it in parens and pressing enter after 'Send Top Form to REPL').

Answer (score 8):

Open File --> Settings --> Keymap

Click on the "Collapse all" to be able to find the options easily

Then go to Main Menu --> Tools --> REPL

You will have there all the actions for the REPL. The specific one that you are asking for is "Run top form in REPL"

Comment: or in keymap windows just search `send top form to repl`

Answer (score 1):

<***Alt-Shift-P***> (Send the surrounding expression to REPL) with [Cursive](https://cursive-ide.com/userguide/index.html) 1.9.0. As mentioned, under Tools/REPL